# membership provider throws trigger exception after upgrading MySql connector

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, mysql-connector

I've just recently upgraded the MySQL Connector/net from 6.5.3 to 6.5.4 and have found that the membership provider no longer works as it did with the old connector. Now, when I attempt to verify a user, the provider throws the following exception:

```
TRIGGER command denied to user 'root'@'%' for table 'my_aspnet_membership'
```

I'm reasonably sure that the above is not related to permissions, as this very same trigger works in my prod and staging environments.

I've also checked the trust level and setting, but even changes to various levels of trust hasn't changed the end result.

*edit*

The exception is being thrown on the `Membership.ValidateUser` method, which is provided by the provider, so there's nothing custom happening during validation.

```
string username = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(emailAddress);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
{
    if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password.Text))
    {
    ... 
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to verify the user?